# Datatables. How to roundup to 1 decimal point?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the DataTables jQuery plugin. I'm using the `footerCallback` function and I have managed to get the total of a column in my table. How do I then roundup the resulting total to 1 decimal point? Eg, 23.1.

This is the `footerCallback` code I'm using:

```
var table_companies = $('#table_companies').dataTable({
"ajax": "data.php?job=get_companies",
"sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
"pagingType": "full_numbers",
"autoWidth": true,
"searching": false,
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 6 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 6, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(
            + total
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[toFixed(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will give 1 decimal place of precision

```js
var one = 1.07,
  two = 2.55,
  three = 3.31,
  total = one + two + three;

alert('Total:           ' + total + '\ntoFixed(1):  ' + total.toFixed(1));
```